# Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react___default.a.createContext is not a function in React project

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have been working on React project using MaterialUI.
Originally I was using `react-materialize` package and it worked.

When I installed `@material-ui/core` package to use MaterialUI components, I got following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react___default.a.createContext is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.min.js:40786)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.min.js:660)
    at fn (index.min.js:86)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.min.js:74914)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.min.js:660)
    at fn (index.min.js:86)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.min.js:26652)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.min.js:660)
    at fn (index.min.js:86)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.min.js:74393)
:8083/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Packages I am using:

```
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-animated-number": "^0.4.2",
    "react-chartjs": "^0.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-leaflet": "^1.1.4",
    "react-materialize": "^1.0.4",
    "react-modal": "^1.7.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0-beta.8",
    "react-table": "^5.6.0",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.4.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.4.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

[`material-ui/core` v4.4.2 package](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.4.2/packages/material-ui/package.json#L36) declares a `React 16.8.0` as a [`peerDependency`](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/).

It uses the new [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) introduced in the `React 16`.

You can either [upgrade your React version to 16](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#upgrading) or use a version of `material-ui/core` package using the [older context API](https://react-legacy.netlify.com/docs/context.html).